# jQuery get text from element while trigger("mouseenter") on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i get the text from an element while triggering 'hover' action on another element?

This is an example:
http://factory.jcrew.com/girls-clothing/swim/rashguards/PRDOVR~A3090/A3090.jsp?color_name=shocking-pink-ivory#

I want to get all colors, but the color names are displayed only when hovering the color box.

This is what i tried:

```
$("#color1 div[data-color='KS8866']").trigger("mouseenter",function() {
var color = $("span.color-name").text();
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `on()` instead of `trigger` to bind the mouse enter event. The jQuery on *Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements, [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/on/)*. *The trigger Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)*. You have to have event handler first.

```
$("#color1 div[data-color='KS8866']").on("mouseenter",function() {
     var color = $("span.color-name").text();
});
```